# Ubuntu Software VirtualEnv

Tags: 14.04

This is my Challenge.

Is there any software that can act as a container for third party ubuntu softwares installations without touching the other dependencies.

Just like python-virtualenv, a software similar to it but for Linux.

I always have troubles of a software asking for newer version of some dependencies while some old ones need the older dependencies or just to allow newer and old dependencies be still kept on the computer without being overwritten or removed. Is it possible to set a virtual env for Linux.

Comment: So basically you need a way to install multiple incompatible versions of the same package on the same system, ideally in a way that each application sees only the one that is suitable for it? (I have no idea how to do this, just trying to clarify your question)

Comment: Exactly @ByteCommander